# Entity framework with GuID

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, guid

I have to generate a GuID in a row of my Database.

I have this code:
public partial class Nouveaucontact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private PROJECTEntities1 db = new PROJECTEntities1();

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string newGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        Clients objAdd = new Clients
        {
            Numero_siret = TextBox_numero_siret.Text,
            Numero_telephone = TextBox_numero_telephone.Text,
            Adresse_mail = TextBox_adressemail.Text,
            Logiciel = DropDownList_choixlogiciel.SelectedValue,

        };

        db.Clients.Add(objAdd);
        db.SaveChanges();                                      
    }
```

I don't know to generate this Unique Identifier.

Comment: Since you are going for a one layer architecture, I suggest just mashing the guid genration into the creation of the client object..  `new Client { id = Guid.NewGuid(), ...`

Comment: Thanks,i make this: Clients objAdd = new Clients
            {
                Numero_siret = TextBox_numero_siret.Text,
                Numero_telephone = TextBox_numero_telephone.Text,
                Adresse_mail = TextBox_adressemail.Text,
                Logiciel = DropDownList_choixlogiciel.SelectedValue,

                GuID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            };